# Cloning html element without data sharing in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form on my page with two text area fields, now i have a button for dynamically adding a new text area + checkbox to the form. I used clone() function to achieve this and it worked but i realized that for the checkbox after it had been clone i was unable to check or uncheck it also it took the checked state of the original element.

**this is the html:**

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="icheckbox_polaris">
  <input style="position: absolute; top: 10%; left: 10%; display: block; width: 80%; height: 80%; 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="check" required="required" name="correctAnswer" value="" type="checkbox">
  <ins style="position: absolute; top: 10%; left: 10%; display: block; width: 80%; height: 80%; 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
</div>
```

**This is my javascript:**

```
$('#lnkAddNewAnswer').click(function() {
   $('.answer-txt-area').first().clone().appendTo('.answers-container')
});
```

I am using the iCheck plugin for my checkboxes and radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your JS to pass a parameter of "true" to the clone method it will clone all events and data as well.

See this [link](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for more info.

```
$('#lnkAddNewAnswer').click(function() {
   $('.answer-txt-area').first().clone(true).appendTo('.answers-container')
});
```

If you have are having further issues it might be a better solution to write out a new checkbox rather than cloning.

Something along the lines of this:

```
$('#lnkAddNewAnswer').click(function() {
   var checkboxHTML = '<input type="checkbox"/>';
   $('.answers-container').append(checkboxHTML);
   $('input').iCheck();
});
```

Comment: Thank you but i already know this and i do not intend to clone data and event handlers as well. As for writing out a new checkbox i did explain that i wanted them to be generated dynamically at the push of a button also i am using a certain plugin for my checkboxes it's a long story which is not at all related to my question but to put it simply writing out a new checkbox is not an option for me i need to clone my existing one. :)

Comment: But can't you write out a new checkbox with your click event and then reinitialise iCheck?

Comment: I have added an edit to try to show you the sort of thing I meant.